# Oracle RAC 11g creation

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, rac

I would like to play with RAC configuration.

Using virtual area (VMware or VirtualBox):

1. RAC1 (Windows 2003 Server)
2. RAC2 (Windows 2003 Server)
3. Shared storage (Openfiler)
4. DNS server (for using SCAN feature)

In process of RAC config I will need to insert static IP address, subnet mask, gateway. Is it possible to create RAC configuration in virtual area, not touching work Active Directory network (I mean not adding IP to working office network)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  When you set up a RAC, you have a set of IP addresses:  Public, for access to the RAC cluster and Interconnect, for interoperation between the RAC nodes.  If you can create your own VNets, you can do this easily.

Comment: Using vmware player or virtual box, the networking becomes a bit of a nightmare.  You can set up multiple NICs on the client machines and assign them fixed IP addresses.  The danger is in mixing them - you can use, for example 10.0.0.x as public and 192.168.0.x as the interconnects.  When you set up the cluster, you will have to run the VIP utility (VIPCA) again as it will fail on the private IP addresses.  Do you need to be able to access them from a machine other than the host?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible both with `VMware` and `VirtualBox` and any other mainstream virtualization product as well I guess.

On my `VMware vSphere` sandbox, I have created an additional virtual switch that is not mapped to any physical network adapters. This network is not visible/reachable from the outside world, but VMs attached to it can reach each other through interfaces using this switch, so it's perfect for a RAC private network with 1 host machine.

In `VirtualBox`, I use `NAT Network` (available since version 4.3) for RAC private network. It's a similar concept, a virtual network not visible/reachable from the outside world, but VMs with interfaces in this network can communicate each other through it.

You can use the above for RAC public networks as well, so you don't need to allocate any IP addresses on your real physical network. For example, in `VirtualBox`, you can use 1 `NAT` network interface as "management interface", and define port forwarding rules on it, so you can access the VM from your local machine thorugh RDP/SSH without using the VM console. Then use another `NAT Network` interface for the RAC public network, and another `NAT Network` interface for the RAC private network, so 3 interfaces in total.

I would not bother with `openfiler`, both `VMware` and `VirtualBox` support shared virtual disks.

Comment: Some guides how to implement configuration you wrote would be helpful to me. For having full picture of all architecture, i need some guide. Can you provide it? I found some posts saying that RAC SCAN not working with NAT. Is it true? How do I test failover?